# Automatic loading of new entries from server into ScrollView as user scrolls down

Tags: java, android, scrollview, android-scrollview

Let me briefly explain my activity structure.  When the user enters the app, they are immediately sent to a fragment displaying a ScrollView, containing a series of layouts.  The layouts are populated from data pulled from a server, with the first ten or so loaded on the creation of the fragment.  As the user scrolls down the ScrollView, I would like new layouts to be added to the bottom of the ScrollView so that all of the data does not have to be gathered from the server at once, and so that the list of entries does not exceed the size it needs to be.

An example of this would be Facebook's news feed on their android app, or Instagram's scrolling pictures.  The Gmail app also has this behavior, loading emails on an as needed basis.  In all cases, new data is loaded as the user scrolls down the page.

My question is, how best can this type of behavior be implemented?

I am defining best as:

- The most efficient
- The most portable (functional on the most phones and most API versions)
- The easiest to maintain and expand upon
- Follows accepted Android standards and conventions

To be clear, I am not simply looking for *a* solution, but *the best* solution.  I am aware that there are multiple ways to implement this behavior, but I am looking for a definitive solution.  Please include a few sentences explaining why your method is the best.  Thank you.

Comment: So in iOS, you can check if the scroll view has reached the bottom **and** you can tell how far the scroll view has scrolled towards the bottom. Can you do this with an Android delegate of ScrollView?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this class for load more items from server

public class LoadMoreListView extends ListView implements OnScrollListener {

```
private static final String TAG = "LoadMoreListView";

/**
 * Listener that will receive notifications every time the list scrolls.
 */
private OnScrollListener mOnScrollListener;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

// footer view
private RelativeLayout mFooterView;
// private TextView mLabLoadMore;
private ProgressBar mProgressBarLoadMore;

// Listener to process load more items when user reaches the end of the list
private OnLoadMoreListener mOnLoadMoreListener;
// To know if the list is loading more items
private boolean mIsLoadingMore = false;
private int mCurrentScrollState;

public LoadMoreListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public LoadMoreListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public LoadMoreListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context) {

    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // footer
    mFooterView = (RelativeLayout) mInflater.inflate(
            R.layout.load_more_footer, this, false);
    /*
     * mLabLoadMore = (TextView) mFooterView
     * .findViewById(R.id.load_more_lab_view);
     */
    mProgressBarLoadMore = (ProgressBar) mFooterView
            .findViewById(R.id.load_more_progressBar);

    addFooterView(mFooterView);

    super.setOnScrollListener(this);
}

@Override
public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
    super.setAdapter(adapter);
}

/**
 * Set the listener that will receive notifications every time the list
 * scrolls.
 * 
 * @param l
 *            The scroll listener.
 */
@Override
public void setOnScrollListener(AbsListView.OnScrollListener l) {
    mOnScrollListener = l;
}

/**
 * Register a callback to be invoked when this list reaches the end (last
 * item be visible)
 * 
 * @param onLoadMoreListener
 *            The callback to run.
 */

public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener) {
    mOnLoadMoreListener = onLoadMoreListener;
}

public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    if (mOnScrollListener != null) {
        mOnScrollListener.onScroll(view, firstVisibleItem,
                visibleItemCount, totalItemCount);
    }

    if (mOnLoadMoreListener != null) {

        if (visibleItemCount == totalItemCount) {
            mProgressBarLoadMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // mLabLoadMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return;
        }

        boolean loadMore = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount;

        if (!mIsLoadingMore && loadMore
                && mCurrentScrollState != SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            mProgressBarLoadMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // mLabLoadMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mIsLoadingMore = true;
            onLoadMore();
        }

    }

}

public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

    // bug fix: listview was not clickable after scroll
    if (scrollState == OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        view.invalidateViews();
    }

    mCurrentScrollState = scrollState;

    if (mOnScrollListener != null) {
        mOnScrollListener.onScrollStateChanged(view, scrollState);
    }

}

public void onLoadMore() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onLoadMore");
    if (mOnLoadMoreListener != null) {
        mOnLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
    }
}

/**
 * Notify the loading more operation has finished
 */
public void onLoadMoreComplete() {
    mIsLoadingMore = false;
    mProgressBarLoadMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

/**
 * Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when list reaches the
 * last item (the user load more items in the list)
 */
public interface OnLoadMoreListener {
    /**
     * Called when the list reaches the last item (the last item is visible
     * to the user)
     */
    public void onLoadMore();
}
```

}

this is the custom List view for loading more items from server.you should use LoadMoreListView class for this work.and u can call this class in xml like this

```
     <com.broadpeak.nvoice.utils.LoadMoreListView
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

lmlv = (LoadMoreListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv);
    lmlv.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLoadMore() {

         }
    });
```

if any query then you can contact freely....

Answer (score 0):

The method you are trying to use is called **LazyLoading** 
As a suggested way in Android development you can make use of `recycler views` and `RecyclerAdapter` for attaining this.

First define an Recycler adapter and views and 
 then,you can set an `onScrollListener` to the recycle adapter and it should go like [(Original Source)](https://gist.github.com/ssinss/e06f12ef66c51252563e)

```
public abstract class EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
    public static String TAG = EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener.class.getSimpleName();

    private int previousTotal = 0; // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
    private boolean loading = true; // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
    private int visibleThreshold = 5; // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position before loading more.
    int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;

    private int current_page = 1;

    private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;

    public EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager) {
        this.mLinearLayoutManager = linearLayoutManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
        totalItemCount = mLinearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        firstVisibleItem = mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        if (loading) {
            if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                loading = false;
                previousTotal = totalItemCount;
            }
        }
        if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)
                <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
            // End has been reached

            // Do something
            // like Load from server
            current_page++;

            onLoadMore(current_page);

            loading = true;
        }
    }

    public abstract void onLoadMore(int current_page);
}
```

As you can see you can make server requests at `onScrolled` method as commented which i think you can do with libraries like **RetroFit** or **okHttp**